# How to add 000 as a integer to a listbox vba?

Tags: vba, listbox, integer

I'd like to add all of the numbers from 0 - 100 to a listbox in vba, however each entry needs to be 3 digits and an integer. So, for example, the first three entries in the list box would be 000, 001, 002.

When I try and add them to the listbox using:

`listbox1.AddItem (000)`

It gets corrected to:

`listbox1.AddItem (0)`

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: why as integer not as a string?

Comment: Because I need to be able to increment the number elsewhere on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Well an integer value truncates leading zeroes.  You can use format(integerVal, "000") (as someone suggested but removed) for the add. Then if you need to work with it, use CINT(ListBox1.List(x)) in your calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why add the value as an `integer` not as a `string`?

```
Listbox1.addItem "000"
```

or a simple loop would do using [Format() function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php)

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 100
    ListBox1.AddItem Format(i, "000")
Next i
```

To extract the value as an Integer use

```
dim value as long
value = ListBox1.List(1)
```

Comment: Because I need to be able to increment the number elsewhere on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Convert it back to an integer or long when you read it from the listbox.

Comment: @BarneyG This is the workaround you are requesting. You are attempting to add a string and pretend that it is an integer. If what matters to you is the formatting, use a string and convert to an integer for calculations.